# Ordering rows and two-levels strips in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, strip

I would like to present data faceted by two variables, each of them having three levels (species `1`, `-2`, and `-3`; and then this level `Y1`, `Y2`, and `Y3`). This itself is not a problem (see picture below).

The problem is to gather the rows `Y2`, `Y1` and `Y3` (in this order) related to the same species, and additionally to get a group species strip, covering the three Y strips of each species.

Do you know how this can be achieved?

**Graphics code**

```
data$VarY = factor(data$VarY, levels=c("Y2","Y1","Y3"))
ggplot(data, aes(Group, VarX, colour = Group)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    facet_grid(VarY + species ~ .) + 
    coord_flip()
```

[picture](http://d.pr/i/zk6D)

Comment: Make up an example using reproducible data, e.g. using the built-in dataset `mtcars`. Just do `data(mtcars)` and the so-named `data.frame` will be available in your R session.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? I give an example of the way you are plotting on the right.

```
data( iris )
iris$Petal.Class <- cut( iris$Petal.Length , 3 )

p1 <- ggplot( iris ) +
  geom_boxplot( aes( Species , Sepal.Width ) ) +
  facet_grid( Species + Petal.Class ~ . )

p2 <- ggplot( iris ) +
  geom_boxplot( aes( Species , Sepal.Width ) ) +
  facet_grid( Species ~ Petal.Class )

require( gridExtra )
grid.arrange( p1 , p2 , nrow = 1 , ncol = 2 )
```

[image]

If you really just want to alter the grouping, just swap the variable names round in your faceting formula, e.g.

```
 facet_grid( species + varY ~ .) +
```

Comment: To me it's important to keep only one dimension to the faceting. And swap the variable names in the faceting formula as you suggest places the species strip on the inner side. I would like the three species strip labels to be on the outter side of the graph, and to overlap the three Y2, Y1 and Y3 facet strips.